# Initialising constexpr - " illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression"

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, constexpr, stdmap

I have two `enum class` types: Type and SocketType. The following code won't compile and fails with the message mentioned in the question, in VC++ 2017:

```
static constexpr std::map<Type,SocketType> PacketTypeMap =
    {
        {Type::JUSTJOINED,      SocketType::TCP},
        {Type::CHAT_MESSAGE,    SocketType::TCP},
        {Type::REQUEST_WORLD,   SocketType::TCP},
        {Type::DATA_WORLD,      SocketType::TCP},
        {Type::DATA_PLAYER,     SocketType::UDP},
        {Type::RESPAWN_PLAYER,  SocketType::TCP}
    };
```

Been trying some variations and nothing works, but I'm sure I'm just missing something simple with the syntax.

Comment: A `std::map` constructor is not `constexpr`.  Its implementation is expected to require information not known until runtime.

Comment: There are no constexpr maps. It uses dynamic allocation, which is not possible with constexpr. Get rid of constexpr, or use a different container for compile-type map.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I should just use const instead in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyA Answers go not in comments, thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe this doesn't reach to the quality of an answer. Good answer would suggested a constexpr friendly associative container with implementation. On the other hand, further clarification from OP indicates that they are not interested in compile-time map, just an immutable map... Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SergeyA You don't have to post an answer if you don't feel you can write one of sufficient quality, but it definitely doesn't go in the comments! Anyway, I think it's good enough

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` is not compatible with `constexpr`. There exists an experimental(?) library called [frozen](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen/), which provides a `constexpr`-compatible `frozen::map` (besides `frozen::unordered_map`, `frozen::string`, and others).

However, most probably you just want to pick a simpler solution (e.g., a `switch` statement in a constexpr function).

Answer (score 3):

Migrating the answer from the comments section into the answer section.

> There are no constexpr maps. It uses dynamic allocation, which is not possible with constexpr. Get rid of constexpr, or use a different container for compile-type map.